# java XML equivalent to flexjson.JSONDeserializer and flexjson.JSONSerializer

Tags: java, xml, json

I have some Java code that is using flexjson.JSONDeserializer and flexjson.JSONSerializer. (simply speaking JSONDeserializer creates an class instance using property value pairs from a String of JSON and JSONSerializer takes a class instance and creates a String of JSON.)

And now I have a need to also use something similar for XML, what is the best match and is there something similar but that has better performance?

simple example

```
class X {
    private Integer a;
    public void setA(Integer a);
    public Integer getA(); 
}

with json equal to {"a":1} I have the following
new JSONDeserializer<X>().use(null, X.class).deserialize(json);

with json equal to [{"a":1},{"a":2}]
new JSONDeserializer<List<X>>().use(null, ArrayList.class).use("values", X.class).deserialize(json);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit
[Comparision of XStream and JAXB here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html)
I still need to compare them again.
End Edit

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) seems easier than the JAXB option since I am also dealing with collections of X

code of serialization is simply

```
return new XStream().toXML(collection);
```

Maven dependences are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlpull</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and in your java file add

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing "dumb" serialization/deserialization of Java objects to/from XML, your best bet is to use the static methods of the [javax.xml.bind.JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html) class. The `marshal()` and `unmarshal()` methods should provide similar functionality to what you are utilizing flexjson for. However, I cannot speak to performance.

Comment: Thanks.  The page you reference says "performance is not necessarily optimal"